# No error encrypting / decrypting data with an expired certificate using RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, encryption, encryption-asymmetric, x509certificate2

I currently doing a proof of concept to encrypt data using a certificate. It works well but now, I want to try a scenario when the certificate is expired. I created an expired certificate and I was surprise to notice that everthing works property even with the expired certificate. I was expecting an error.

Do you know if it's because it's a self signed certificate ?

Here's the code I using to test my case

```
[TestMethod]
public void Encrypt_decrypt_with_expired_certificate()
{
    //Arrange
    var baseString = "This is an encryption test";
    X509Certificate2 newX509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2("d:\\testx509certExpired.pfx", "apassword");
    Console.WriteLine(newX509Certificate2.NotAfter); //Show the expiration date which is in the past
    var encryptor = new CertificateEncryptor(newX509Certificate2); //This class is a simple wrapper around RSACryptoServiceProvider

    //Act
    string encryptedResult = encryptor.Encrypt(baseString); //Exception expected because of the expired certificate but not thrown

    //Assert
    Console.WriteLine("Base string : {0}", baseString);
    Console.WriteLine("Encrypted string : {0}", encryptedResult);
    Assert.IsNotNull(encryptedResult);

    //revert back
    string decryptedString = encryptor.Decrypt(encryptedResult);
    Console.WriteLine("Decrypted string : {0}", decryptedString);
    Assert.AreEqual(baseString, decryptedString);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Probably best suited for Code Review in my opinion.

Comment: If you want to use an expired certificate the X509Certificate2 class isn't going to stop you. It does provide you with methods to check the expiration so you can write the code to detect the condition and react appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As GregS said, `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class (not X509Certificate2) provides an ability to perform cryptographic operations. `RSACryptoServiceProvider` knows nothing about certificate, it knows only keys and their parameters. This is why you don't see any errors.

This means that certificate validation -- is your app responsibility. You should check certificate when encrypting data and skip all certificate checks to decrypt data.

Comment: To add to this, the 'keys' in the certificate are not actually 'expireable'. The 'expriy' on the certificate is ASN1 object on the certificate that is independant from the keys.

Comment: I don't believe this is the case anymore. When I've tried to cast a certificate public key as a RSACryptoServiceProvider object by attempting to access the X509Certificate2.PublicKey.Key attribute, a CryptographicException is thrown indicating simply "Bad key".  This is .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0):

When attempting to access the X509Certificate2.PublicKey.Key attribute of the certificate, a CryptographicException should be thrown if the certificate is not within its validity period.

Here is how I load the public & private keys from a certificate to perform cryptographic operations:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

class Example

{
    private RSACryptoServiceProvider publicKey,
                                     privateKey;

    private bool getRSAKeys(X509Certificate2 cert, StoreLocation location)
    {
        try
        {
            //This will throw a CryptographicException if the certificate is expired
            publicKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;

            privateKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
            return true;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The certificate is expired or otherwise unusable\r\n" + e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```